# Why do I get NS range exception crash on iPad?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I received a certain number of crash reports on Firebase, all of which happen on iPad.

```
Fatal Exception: NSRangeException
*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 5 beyond bounds [0 .. 4]
_CFDataInit


Fatal Exception: NSRangeException
0  CoreFoundation                 0x1ae9139d8 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x1c2c7cb54 objc_exception_throw
2  CoreFoundation                 0x1ae97dd98 -[__NSCFString characterAtIndex:].cold.1
3  CoreFoundation                 0x1ae7fcb84 _CFDataInit
4  UIKitCore                      0x1b09d6630 -[UITabBarController _viewControllerForTabBarItem:]
5  UIKitCore                      0x1b09d6690 -[UITabBarController _tabBarItemClicked:]
```

Is there a way to find out about and fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is: Apple will add an extra tab bar item under certain circumstances. That extra tab bar item is positioned somewhere at the right side of the tab bar. It is invisible, but if you or your user accidentally tapped on it, it will trigger an out of range error.

A simple solution is to run the following code at the appropriate time.

```
        // If you started your app project with Apple's Tabbed App template, that is your root view controller. 
        guard let rootViewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.first(where: { $0.isKeyWindow })?.rootViewController as? UITabBarController,
              let items = rootViewController.tabBar.items else {return}
        for item in items {
            //Find the tab bar item that has no title, which means it is added by Appple automatically
            guard item.title == nil else {continue}
            //Disable it so that it won't trigger a _tabBarItemClicked event
            item.isEnabled = false
        }
```

**How did I find out why this crash happens?**

The obvious hint is the _tabBarItemClicked in the crash report. It leads to an index of 5. But my app has only five tab bar items drawn in the main storyboard. I then use XCode's view debugger to check out the view hierarchy. It indeed has 6 bar items.

I did some extra digging, and figured out why that extra bar item is added. It's because I have a launch ad that covers the full view of the app when the app is launching. When I create that view, Apple some how thinks my tab view bar has more than 5 items and added a "more" item automatically.

**Why don't I change the way the launch ad is presented?**

I guess if I use a view controller rather than a tab view controller as the root view, Apple might not add that extra bar item. But then I'll have to embed a tab view controller inside a view controller for the whole life cycle of the app. The current solution, I think, is much safer and efficient. Of course, in the future, switching to Swift UI and protocols would avoid a lot potential problems like this.